# What's the best class to store the network identity of a computer in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

On Windows, a computer can be located using its Netbios name, DNS name, IPv4 or IPv6 name.

Is there a built in class in the .net Framework that can aggregate all these ways of identifying a computer?

The `Uri` class can detect DNS, IPv4/v6, but I would have to specify a "fake" scheme if I wanted to use it and I'm not sure it's the best way to go.

Comment: Identify it for what use?  Are you looking for `string` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727609/best-way-to-create-ipendpoint-from-string/12044845#12044845

Comment: A computer exposes many different interfaces for its various functions. Thus it is impossible to define a class named `Computer` to encapsulate all, and no doubt Microsoft does not provide one in .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for misunderstanding. [IPHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mostly used to store such data in .NET Framework. But it's not very rich for functionality.. Own custom class may be an better solution...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and still don't understand how I couldn't find it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[IPHostEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.iphostentry?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) is probably not quite correct to use for storing IP or hostname. Because it is a "live class", the data will be dynamically filled.

I think the [DnsEndPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dnsendpoint?view=net-6.0) class will be optimal for use