# Using RegularExpression for Getting Parts of IP and Port Numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use Regular Expression in C# Visual Studio 2013, I need to get a string that looks like this  192.168.1.254:65.
What I need to do is break this string into two values an IP Address and a Port number, Everything to the left of the colon is going to be the IP Address and Everything to the right of the colon is going to be the port, I need to do this with a regular expression in C# Code. So please place any namespaces that need to be added in the code to use the regular expression in C#, Example below

```
string mystring = "192.168.1.254:65";

string myipaddress = RegularExpressionMethod(ExpressionToGetIp, mystring);
string myportnumber = RegularExpressionMethod(ExpressionToGetPort, mystring);
```

This has nothing to do with IPEndPoints its a general abstraction method

Comment: Can you not just split it by the colon?

Comment: How, if the ip port is larger than two numbers I need to get everything from the right and everything from the left of the colon but I don't need the colon that's just marker point to distinguish the port from the ip.

Comment: @shawn Do you know what you are talking about? read the Ben's answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to create IPEndpoint from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727609/best-way-to-create-ipendpoint-from-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the [`.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
string mystring = "192.168.1.254:65";

string[] s = mystring.Split(':');
string ip = s[0]; // "192.168.1.254"
string port = s[1]; // "65"
```

If you need to double check the IP and Port numbers are in the right format, you can add the `System.Net;` namespace, then parse each string:

```
try
{
    IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    int PortNum = Int32.Parse(port);
}
catch
{ 
    // catch any exceptions here
}
```

Or a simpler method might be (courtesy of [EZI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2345956/ezi) for reminding me) using the [`.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This is a bit easier to deal with, as this outputs a `bool`.

```
IPAddress IP;
int PortNum;

if (IPAddress.TryParse(s[0], out IP)) // If it is a valid IP
    { MessageBox.Show("IP address in correct format"); }
else { MessageBox.Show("IP address not in correct format"); }

if (Int32.TryParse(s[1], out PortNum)) // If it is a valid Port Number
    { MessageBox.Show("Port Number in correct format"); }
else { MessageBox.Show("Port Number not in correct format"); }
```

Comment: And a final correction may be using `TryParse` method instead of catching exception.

Answer (score 3):

You could not reinvent the wheel and say something like this:

```
string myString = "192.168.1.254:65";

UriBuilder uri  = new UriBuilder("http://" + myString );
string     host = uri.Host ;
int        port = uri.Port ;
```

You could simply say:

```
string[] parts = myString.Split(":");
string host = parts[0] ;
string port = parts[1] ;
```

But you should be aware that this will break if you get IPv6 address literals.

You could use a regular expression:

```
Regex rx = new Regex( @"^(?<host>.+):(?<port>\d+)$");
Match m  = rx.Match(myString);

if ( !m.Success ) throw new FormatException() ;

string host =            m.Groups["host"].Value   ;
int    port = int.Parse( m.Groups["port"].Value ) ;
```

Or you could get all fancy-like and write an extension method:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public static DnsEndPoint ToDnsEndpoint( this string text)
  {
    Match m = rxDnsEndpoint.Match(text);
    if ( !m.Success ) throw new FormatException("invalid endpoint format");

    string        host     =            m.Groups["host"].Value   ;
    int           port     = int.Parse( m.Groups["port"].Value ) ;
    IPAddress     address  ;
    bool          parsed   = IPAddress.TryParse( host , out address ) ;
    AddressFamily family   = parsed ? address.AddressFamily : AddressFamily.Unspecified ;
    DnsEndPoint   endpoint = new DnsEndPoint( host , port , family ) ;
    return endpoint;
  }
  private static Regex rxDnsEndpoint = new Regex( @"^(?<host>.+):(?<port>\d+)$");
}
```

Which lets you say things like

```
DnsEndpoint endpoint = myString.ToDnsEndpoint() ;
```

Comment: No need to down vote if it still answers the question though