# Removing the port from a IP string that is IPv6 safe in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ipv6

I need the IP without port on users that make requests in a rest API running on ASP.NET MVC. It seems the way to get the address is a combination of these:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Which give me a string with IP:Port

IPV4 is simple, but from reading I expect IPV6 will give me something like this:

```
[1fff:0:a88:85a3::ac1f]:8001
```

IPAddress.Parse can handle IPv6 with port but not IPv4 with port which is strange.

I could inspect the string to see what kind of address it is, but I feel like there should be a better way.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not going to mark this as duplicate, but this answer might interest you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12044845/3032289 Using an `Uri` might also be an option, though it's... not entirely clean.

Comment: Similar approach to my current version, really expected there to be a framework way to do this, like IPEndpoint.Parse. But looks like this will have to do.

Comment: Well, to be fair, including the port in an IP address isn't exactly normalized data. Those really should be two separate fields, since there's no standard for IP endpoints, unlike IP addresses and ports. Also, note that `X-Forwarded-For` *should* contain all the proxies on the way, including the original client, separated by commas. And of course, it's not reliable. `UserHostAddress` will only give you the latest address in the chain, which will tend to be the last router between the client and your server. If you can avoid using the IP address, do so - it's unreliable and annoying.

Comment: The API is used for registration of game servers to a master server. IP Addresses are fed to other clients so they can connect to the game server. The last router in the chain is the only useful information in this case as the game server must have an open port to their external IP to be connectable in the game. I should have read up more on X_FORWARDED_FOR it appears I shouldn't use that at all. Either way problem is the same.

Comment: A better way to fetch the endpoint from ASP.NET MVC would be a better solution.

Comment: Why not just let the game servers... send you their IP address? That's quite a common approach, really...

Comment: Making the game server do a web request to get its own external IP address seems like a much worse work around than inspecting a string to see if it is IPv6. Also the game servers can't be trusted, an attacker could add false server records that point to active ports on other servers to spam them. At Least this way I can trust that the IP is somewhat correct.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my makeshift version in the mean time

```
public string StripPortFromEndPoint(string endPoint)
{
    var splitList = endPoint.Split(':');
    if (splitList.Length > 2)
    {
        endPoint = IPAddress.Parse(endPoint).ToString();
    }
    else if (splitList.Length == 2)
    {
        endPoint = splitList[0];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ParseException("No port separator found",0);
    }

    return endPoint;
}
```