# Splitting a string arrays into two different arrays

Tags: c#

It's required to split each string from networkList array into `addresses` and `ports` arrays.

```
string[] networkList = { "127.0.0.1:8000", "127.0.0.1:8888", "8.8.8.8:80" };
string[] addresses, ports;
```

I'm really sorry of asking so dumby question, but I couldn't find a good function to do this. I know there are few that could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create IPEndpoint from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727609/best-way-to-create-ipendpoint-from-string)

Comment: @saarrrr I tried of creating a loop which loops through all the array strings, so basically <code>Array.length</code> and then had no idea what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each string in `networkList` you can split it by `:`, taking the first part as `addresses` and the second as `ports`:

```
string[] networkList = { "127.0.0.1:8000", "127.0.0.1:8888", "8.8.8.8:80" };

string[] addresses = networkList.Select(s => s.Split(':')[0]).ToArray();
string[] ports = networkList.Select(s => s.Split(':')[1]).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

`but I couldn't find a good function to do this.` Then write one yourself

```
string[] networkList = { "127.0.0.1:8000", "127.0.0.1:8888", "8.8.8.8:80" };

var res = networkList.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
         .Select(x => new { Address = x[0], Port = x[1] });
```